# Merge / Update query to update

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables named CONTACT AND ROLES.

CONTACT TABLE LOOKS LIKE BELOW

| CONTACT_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | PHONE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 59285 | AAA | BBB | 99999 |
| 59281 | AAA | BBB | 99999 |
| 59288 | ZZZ | YYY | 11111 |
| 59282 | ZZZ | YYY | 11111 |

basically diff contact ids but same FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,  PHONE

ROLES TABLE LOOKS LIKE

| CONTACT_ID |
| --- |
| 59285 |
| 59281 |
| 59288 |
| 59282 |

I want to update the ROLES table, referencing the contact table to the minimum of the duplicate contact id so that the ROLES table looks like

| CONTACT_ID |
| --- |
| 59281 |
| 59281 |
| 59282 |
| 59282 |

I am trying using merge

```
MERGE INTO ROLES T1 USING(
    SELECT
        MIN(CONTACT_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE) AS min_contact_id
    FROM CONTACT
) T2 ON (T1.ROWID = T2.ROWID) WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET  T1.CONTACT_ID = T2.min_contact_id;
```

but it just gives output as 0 rows merged.

Comment: Maybe your " when matched then" = false? and you need to write "when not matched then"?

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
select distinct a.first_name,b.contact_id, a.min_id
from (

    select first_name, min(contact_id) as min_id
    from contact
    group by contact_id) as a inner join contact b on a.first_name = b.first_name
)

update roles set roles.contact_id = cte.min_id
from cte inner join roles on roles.contact_id = cte.contact_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your MERGE statement to a simple UPDATE statement -

```
UPDATE ROLES R
   SET CONTACT_ID = (SELECT MIN_CONTACT_NO
                       FROM (SELECT CONTACT_ID, MIN(CONTACT_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE) MIN_CONTACT_NO
                               FROM LOOKS) L
                      WHERE L.CONTACT_ID = R.CONTACT_ID);
```

As their ROWIDs never going to be same which was not correct in your query.

[DB Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7b70e304224f5dc5df8723d2903d3217)

Comment: The columns that are used in the ON clause cannot be updated, so CONTACT_ID can be in either the ON clause or the update clause.

Comment: @Saafi, Please try the updated statement with the fiddle attached.